# I am getting Parsing error: Unexpected token in VS code

Tags: reactjs

I am getting Failed to compile ,Parsing error: Unexpected token in localhost 3000 for this React code. How to fix it?

```
class Employee extends React.Component{
      function addEmployee() {
        alert("Adding a  new employee !");
      }
      render(){
        return
          <div>
            <h2>  Welcome to Employee Component. </h2>
            <p> <button onClick={this.addEmployee}> Add Employee</button></p>
          </div>
      
     
    }
const element = <Employee></Employee>
 ReactDOM.render(element,document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: classes don't use the `function` keyword. Also, don't ever use `alert`, use the Console API (`console.log`, etc). Alert is from an era when blocking the JS thread was fine. That hasn't been the case for about a decade now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 errors:

1. convert `function addEmployee() {` to `addEmpoyee() {`
2. move `<div>` to the same line of return; or add parethensis.
3. Missing one close `}`. Add it before `const element`

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a parenthesis to your return.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>  Welcome to Employee Component. </h2>
      <p> <button onClick={this.addEmployee}> Add Employee</button></p>
    </div>
   );           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactor your function to arrow syntax

````
addEmployee = () => {
        alert("Adding a  new employee !");
      }```
````